# Google Play rejection due to Accessibility API Policy: Missing prominent disclosure in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, accessibility, google-play-console, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api

I recently updated my Flutter app on the Google Play Store to include a Pin Live Score functionality. This feature uses the AccessibilityService API in conjunction with the flutter_overlay_window (version 0.4.3) and flutter_accessibility_service (version 0.2.4) packages to display live cricket scores in a small pop-up overlay when the app is in the foreground.

However, the app update was rejected by Google Play with the error message:

> Accessibility API Policy: Missing prominent disclosure
> Details :
> We were unable to approve your app because we could not locate prominent disclosure of your use of the AccessibilityService API in your app.
>
> Please update your app so that the prominent disclosure meets all the requirements as defined in the [User Data Policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311).

I have already added a disclosure about the use of the AccessibilityService API in the app's long description, but it seems that it is not meeting the requirements. I want to seek guidance on how to craft a prominent disclosure that complies with Google's policies.

Here's an example of the current disclosure in my app's long description:

> Accessibility Feature:
>
> Pin Scoring for Instant Cricket Updates
>
> In CrickZone, we've introduced an innovative Pin Scoring feature that allows you to stay updated on live cricket scores with just a click. When you tap the Pin Scoring icon, a small, non-intrusive pop-up appears, providing you with real-time cricket scores right on your screen, even when the app is in the background.
>
> How AccessibilityService API Enhances Pin Scoring:
>
> The AccessibilityService API is employed to facilitate the smooth integration of the Pin Scoring feature. This ensures that users, including those with accessibility needs, can easily access live cricket scores without navigating away from the current screen. The API enables a seamless overlay, enhancing the overall accessibility and user-friendliness of the Pin Scoring feature.
>
> User Privacy and Transparency:
>
> We value your privacy, and it's important to note that the AccessibilityService API is used exclusively for the Pin Scoring feature. No sensitive information is collected, stored, or shared. Our commitment to transparency means that you can use the Pin Scoring feature with confidence, knowing that your data remains secure.
>
> How It Works:
>
> Tap the Pin Scoring icon to view live cricket scores in a convenient pop-up.
> The AccessibilityService API ensures a smooth overlay experience without disrupting your current screen.
> Stay updated on cricket scores seamlessly, even when the app is in the foreground.

I am using the following packages for implementing the Pin Live Score functionality:

flutter_overlay_window: ^0.4.3
flutter_accessibility_service: ^0.2.4

Can someone please provide insights on how to improve the disclosure or any specific steps that need to be taken to ensure compliance with Google's Accessibility API Policy?

I have visited [this website](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311?hl=en) but nothing helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

> I have already added a disclosure about the use of the AccessibilityService API in the app's long description, but it seems that it is not meeting the requirements.

The first of the requirements on the User Data Policy page you linked is "Must be within the app itself, not only in the app description or on a website."

Comment: Yes, it is within the app